# How can I deactivate the print-spooler?

Tags: printing, laserjet

My HP LaserJet 5L needs to print direct because of its USB-Adapter.

How can I deactivate the print-spooler?

Comment: To help us understand, can you clarify what you mean bt "print direct"

Answer (score 0):

The print spooler service allows you to load in memory print jobs for later printing, that is to say, put them in the print queue.

For complete information on how to disable it and other printer system administration, visit the Ubuntu Manuals [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/lpc.8.html).